# Spring Data, Specification, joined Lazy field

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

The problem: entity marked as FetchType.Lazy not inited (has empty fields) when use `Specification`.

Have 2 db tables, entities:
`User`, `Relation`.
1 User: N relations, but actual relation is 1:1 between 2 users.
Mapping in User:

```
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "other")
    public List<Relation> relation;
```

In Relation:

```
    @OneToOne(targetEntity = User.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    public User user;

    @OneToOne(targetEntity = User.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "other_id")
    public User other;
```

Reading using `Specification`:

```
        return spec.and((root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
                    Join<Object, Object> join = root.join("relation", JoinType.LEFT);
                    return criteriaBuilder.and(
                            criteriaBuilder.or(
                                    criteriaBuilder.isNull(join.get("user")),
                                    criteriaBuilder.and(
                                            criteriaBuilder.equal(join.get("user"), user),
                                            criteriaBuilder.equal(join.get("other"), root)
                                    )
                            )
                    );
                }
        );
```

So, after result entities are loaded, I see in debug that `Relation` is present in `User` as 'PersistentBag', all fields are present in **toString()**. But if check actual fields and when code processing it, all fields are null actually... Not sure how this works, may be due to separate thread by code editor.
Why is this actually and how to fix this?

Comment: I don't quite understand this filter - why are you checking if the user is null, and why are you checking that the 'relation' points at 'user' - the join itself from root's 'relation' should cover that. This shouldn't affect the entities returned from the query at all - Are you trying to force a fetch join maybe?

Comment: @Chris i added condition `or user is null` to do `left join`. All other criterias for same purpose. If this is wrong - how to do it properly? Can't find example...

Comment: join.get("user") by definition will create an inner join for the relationship and filter nulls out of the result. JPA will allow it for the isNull operation and it will work as you expect for there, but because you've included it again in the equal user check, it must ensure it is an inner join and nulls are filtered from the query. If you want an outer left join, you should define it as you've done for the relation and use that in both the isNull and Equal expressions. I don't know what you are seeing in your returned entity, but look at the SQL for your query first and the results

Comment: @Chris if i remove condition or `criteriaBuilder.isNull(join.get("user")),` and I've got only matched, like 'inner join' not 'left join'.

Comment: IsNull is not an outer join, and does nothing to force one. Your issue though is with criteriaBuilder.equal(join.get("user"), user), which is an Inner Join, and forces filtering out nulls. Replace all join.get("user") calls with just 'user' from Join<User,Relation> user = join.join("user", JoinType.LEFT); as that specifies you want to use an left outer join for the user which you can then use in the isNull and equals filters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using criteriaBuilder.equal(join.get("user"), user), the spec mandates that JPA providers use an inner join to fetch the user. Inner joins filter out nulls so there aren't any for the criteriaBuilder.isNull(join.get("user")) clause to use. You can verify by looking at the SQL generated; you'll see there is only one join used to the user table despite you have multiple join.get("user") calls.

Instead, you should specify the join type that should be used by JPA:

```
Join<Relation, Object> join = root.join("relation", JoinType.LEFT);
Join<User, Relation> joinedUser = join.join("user", JoinType.LEFT);
return criteriaBuilder.and(
  criteriaBuilder.or(
    criteriaBuilder.isNull(joinedUser),
    criteriaBuilder.and(
      criteriaBuilder.equal(joinedUser, user),
      criteriaBuilder.equal(join.get("other"), root)
    )
  )
);
```

Comment: thanks a lot, seems this is working! But let me ask you, how did you know this? I can't find documentation about this...

Comment: I had thought the spec called it out more specifically, but the best I can find quickly is "4.4.4. Path Expressions" where it states path expressions are inner joins and filter nulls. Otherwise, forums and other places will mention it. I know some providers (EclipseLink) can treat join.get("user") and not actually have to join in the user table and instead just use the FK 'user_id' column directly, but for the most part, you should assume that something like equals(join.get("user"), user) is translated to equals(join.get("user").get("id"), user.id).